# getType method in contentProvider subclass

Tags: android

i searched a lot about this topic 
but i still can't wrap my brain around it

can someone "deeply explains to me " how getType() works ? and few examples that also explains the mime and how it is used when it is returned by getType() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content URIs can be used to reference content from a wide variety of contexts. The `getType` method allows a content consumer - which might be a component in your app, but can also be component outside your app and which doesn't know anything specifically about your app except for the content URI - to find out what type of data a content URI refers to. The content consumer needs this information to know how what to do with the content - for example, how to display it - when it resolves the content URI. So in the simplest case, if the URI `content://my.app/record/1` refers to a HTML file, then the type is *text/html*, and if the URI `content://my.app/record/2` refers to a JPEG file then the type is *image/jpeg*. There is no other way to infer the content type from the URI (because e.g. there's no file extensions).

Android also provides some special MIME types for indicating table data, `android.cursor.item/*` and `android.cursor.dir/*`.

This approach is designed to fit in with Android's `Activity` based architecture, allowing the system to open content URIs by examining the content MIME type and then choosing an Intent to open an Activity which displays the content.

Comment: thanks for the clarification !! how does it choose the right activity to open ?

Comment: is MIME type defined in it so it tells the intent that it is the right activity that can act upon the data or what ?

Comment: That is down to intents and intent filters, see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html Basically, an app can declare an implicit intent that can handle a specified MIME type. When the Android system has to open content with a particular MIME type, it looks at the list of apps with implicit intents for that type, and chooses one. This may mean that the user is presented with a dialog to select the app to use to show content, if more than one intent can handle the content type.